# Yii2 изменить сценарий формы

Tags: yii2

Есть форма. В ней пользователь выбирает (radio) параметр и подгружаются дополнительные поля (из этой же модели). Как динамически изменить сценарий, что бы они валидировались без перегазгруки страницы. Можно пример?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно включить в форме Ajax валидацию, в документации пример: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#ajax-validation

```
public function actionSomeValidate(){
    ...
    $model = new someModel();
    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load($post)) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $model->scenario = $post['scenario'];
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: И менять сценарий? во время валидации? в action?

Comment: мне нужно изменить сценарий в тот момент, когда выбран определенный радиобуттон и подгружены новые поля! вот тут и проблема у меня. не пойму как. Неужели ajax-м всю форму перегружать

Comment: @Роман ajax валидация предпологает запрос в action контроллера и возврат данных в формате json после валидации, вы в вашем экшене получаете все данные из формы (смотрите пример в доке, я про $_POST), что вам мешает в экшене узнать значение вашей кнопки и заменить сценарий перед валидацией?

Answer (score 0):

можно написать свой валидатор, с соответствующей логикой, либо воспользоваться
beforeValidate() модели, где дергать сценарии. И воспользоваться при этом конструкцией из ответа выше.